# Spring boot security, JWT auth server to server

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, jwt

I want to secure my application with JWT. This application is only accessed by other server applications that know the secret key before hand. I do not need to add a token generation since the key is already known between the applications. I tried to find some samples for this, but all the examples are complicated (I'm new to spring security) and moreover they do not include anything simple that would fit my use case (known secret key and algorithm, so no provider and storing of the token is needed). 
Basically what I want is to decode the token sent by the fellow server, check the secret key, check the sender and check the time (the fellow server will always generate a new token so if that token is stollen then it will be invalid in a small amount of time).

I've thought of implementing this with a custom filter (or interceptor) plus [this library](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt) and remove spring security entirely, since I can't find any use for it. But I would prefer to use spring security in order to have it available for any future needs and in general achieve what I want by doing it the spring way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [JWTFilter](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-registry/blob/master/src/main/java/io/github/jhipster/registry/security/jwt/JWTFilter.java) from JHipster may be a good start!